# EPC mode on Seagate Constellation using Linux

Tags: linux, raid, lsi, seagate

I need to set EPC mode on Seagate Constellation disks connected to LSI 9690SA-4l controller. This is because the controller is not compatible with the disks unless the EPC mode is set – according to page http://mycusthelp.info/LSI/_cs/AnswerDetail.aspx?inc=8187

The thing is we can't google any way to set the disk mode using Linux. Is there any Linux tool to set such a mode?

Comment: I've just spent at least 20 minutes looking for this, and my google-foo is reasonably strong, and got nowhere, I know what it does but I'm as confused as you as to how you configure it - sorry. Good question though :)

Answer (score 0):

(dont have enough rep to comment)
Have you considered simply using mono to run the seagate windows utility?